# Distinguish Mitsubishi G6M1-L2 and G4M1 aircraft in this picture

Tags: world-war-two, military, japan, identification, aircraft

Here is a [picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mitsubishi_G4M_auf_Ie_Shima.jpg) of Bataan 1 and Bataan 2:

[image]

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bataan_1_and_Bataan_2):

> Bataan 1 and Bataan 2 were two demilitarized Japanese bomber/transport aircraft that carried the first surrender delegations from Japan to Ie Shima as part of the surrender of Japan in World War II. The two aircraft, specifically a Mitsubishi G6M1-L2 military transport (dubbed Bataan 1) and a second, disarmed and repaired Mitsubishi G4M1 bomber (Bataan 2), carried eight members of the delegation team [...].

Which one is which in the picture?

[Wikipedia article on G4M variants.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitsubishi_G4M#Variants)

Answer (score 15):

The G6M1 were simply G4Ms reconfigured for transport, so the two are practically identical. Nonetheless, the component circled below indicates that the first aircraft is the G4M1.

[image]

That loop is featured on drawings of the G4M1:

[image]
[image]

But not on the G6M1-L2 series.

[image]
[image]

Click to enlarge the above thumbnails.

Comment: That loop is the radio direction finder antenna.

Answer (score 11):

According to [this site](http://www.modelaces.com/148_scale_model/G4M1_Betty_Bomber_Bataan_2.php), the Bataan 2 is the plane pictured in the foreground, distinguishable by more (windows?) on the nose cone area.

[image]

More info can be found at the [Aviation History](http://www.aviation-history.com/mitsubishi/g4m.html) website.
[image]